# Google App Script - getCommenter

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm brand new to Google Apps Script, and I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet that will allow me to share files by user email through a single spreadsheet.

I have written the following script, which will allow me to add editors and viewers, but not commenters.

I keep getting an error that states that the function addCommenter cannot be found in object spreadsheet.

```
function shareSheet () {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.toast('Updating access level...');
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range1 = sheet.getRange (3,1, lastRow,9);
    var data = range1.getValues();

    for (var i= 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data [i];
        var accessLevel = row [5];
        var values = row [8];
        var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(values);
        var values2 = row [4];

        // Add new editor
        if (accessLevel == 'Edit') {
           var addEditors = ss2.addEditor(values2);
        }

        // Add new viewer
        if (accessLevel == 'View'){
            var addViewers = ss2.addViewer(values2);
        }

        // Add new commenter
        if (accessLevel == 'Comment') {
            var addCommenters = ss2.addCommenter(values2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spreadsheet object does not support the addCommentor() method. You should use DriveApp service instead.

```
DriveApp.getFileById(id).addCommenter(emailAddress)
```